# Ublox Neo M8N + wemos lolin32 serial monitor problem

Tags: arduino, serial, esp32, gps, baudrate

So i have a neo m8n that should print my lat and lon to the serial monitor,but fails to do so. Here is the code:

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
TinyGPSPlus gps;
HardwareSerial neogps(1);
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
 neogps.begin(9600,SERIAL_8N1,1,3);
}

void loop() {
  gps.encode(neogps.read());
  if(gps.location.isUpdated())
  {
  
  Serial.print(gps.location.lat(),4);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(gps.location.lng(),4);

  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

If i look on the 9600 baud rate on the serial monitor i see some nmea 0183 sentences and when i used an online convertor to see if the data is correct,i found out they are,but when i switch to the 115200 baud rate all i see is this :
[image]

and it goes on forever. I am stuck